# Wait for all child processes to finish to continue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, child-process

I would like to know if it is possible to wait for all child process created using the `spawn` function to finish before continuing execution.

I have a code looking like this:

```js
    const spawn = window.require('child_process').spawn;

    let processes = [];
    let thing = [];
    // paths.length = 2
    paths.forEach((path) => {
        const pythonProcess = spawn("public/savefile.py", ['-d', '-j', '-p', path, tempfile]);

        pythonProcess.on('exit', () => {
            fs.readFile(tempfile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                thing.push(...)
            });
        });

        processes.push(pythonProcess);
    });

    console.log(processes) // Here we have 2 child processes
    console.log(thing) // empty array.. the python processes didnt finish yet

    return thing // of course it doesn't work. I want to wait for all the processes  to have finished their callbacks to continue
```

As you can guess, I would like to know how I could get all the python scripts running at the same time, and wait for all of them to finish to continue my js code.

I'm running node `10.15.3`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForEach to push Promise into an array of Promise and Promise.all()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options) ?

> Is generally identical to spawn with the exception that the function
> will not return until the child process has fully closed.

```
import { spawnSync } from "child_process";
spawnSync('ls', ['-la']);
```